# text input get focus out of its border

Tags: html, css

im trying to use `input` in `label` element but it get focus out of its border (in left and right side).

What is my code problem?

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
label input
{
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 36px;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#comment
{
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background:  #d9d9d9;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 6px lightblue solid;
}
#name
{  
  width: 35%;
  border: 2px solid #ff5126;
}
#email
{ 
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ff5126;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment">

 <label>
           <input placeholder="Name" type="text" id="name" required/>
 </label>

 <label>
   <input placeholder="E-mail" type="email" id="email" required/>
 </label>

</div>
```

Comment: Why would you use `input` in `label` element in the first place??

Comment: What do you mean by, "...it get focus out of its border"?

Comment: because you made label to be block .. change to inline-block

Comment: @RahulDesai — That's how you associate an input with a label.

Comment: @Quentin I'd do it using `for` attribute.

Comment: @RahulDesai — That's an alternative approach.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for putting text in the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the label element (aside from associating some **text** — which is missing from your code — with the input) is that clicking on the label will focus the input.

Your labels are `display: block`, so they will fill the width of the container.

Add a background colour, border, outline, etc to see where it is.